# Validate number 18.2 with class-validator

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I need to validate `number 18.2` with [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator). On current stage I know how to validate only decimal places:

```js
export class PaymentBasicData {
    /**
     * Transaction amount.
     */
    @Expose()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsNumber({ maxDecimalPlaces: 2 })
    @Min(0.01)
    @Max(999999999999999999.99)
    public amount: number;
}
```

I should validate a `number` with 18 numbers before dot and 2 numbers after dot. How it should looks like?

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: Is it correct to validate `@Max(999999999999999999.99)` or maybe exists other way? Question updated.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? If you need exactly 18 digits before the dot you might use a regular expression. Whether your defined maximum is legit or not is defined by the context of this amount. I usually take the max value of the data type as the upper limit when no other constraint is known.

Answer (score 0):

For the digits part `class-validator` has a `@IsDecimal` validation decorator you can use and it accepts options.

For what I know you cannot validate before coma (or point) digits, the maximum value you already used should work.

```js
import { Expose } from "class-transformer";
import { IsDecimal, IsNoEmpty, Max, Min } from "class-validator";

export class PaymentBasicData {
    /**
     * Transaction amount.
     */
    @Expose()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsDecimal({ decimal_digits: "2" })
    @Min(0.01)
    @Max(999999999999999999.99)
    public amount: number;
}
```